# Error: gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Tags: apt, gnupg, keyserver

I want to install kali linux repository in Ubuntu 18.04

```
apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6
```

This return an error as follow.

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure
```

Comment: THere is a known issue with PGP Keyservers as a result of some nasty CVEs that makes the keyservers very slow to respond and reply.  You may just need to try again at a later time.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399027/gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-server-indicated-a-failure